# How to remove $ and comma from form input using current php code?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, currency, postdata

Here's sample of my input format

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerypriceformat.com/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerypriceformat.com/js/jquery.price_format.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerypriceformat.com/js/ini.js"></script>
<label for="example6">Currency:</label>
<input id="example6" name="example6" value="" type="text">
```

Mysql table type is set to :  `decimal(16,2)`

Here's my problem:

For example:

Input format:  `US$ 625,695,295.00`

Outout format: `625`

It means, it won't save into table as currency correct format, it won't save after comma into sql table. It should be something like this:  `625695295.00`

How to remove it those commas and dollar sign when data is posting to mysql table?

Here's my post code:

```
$problem->setExample6($_POST["example6"]);
$_POST["example6"] = $problem->getExample6();
```

Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION: PROBLEM SOLVED!! SPECIAL THANKS TO  [chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85)
Here we go:

> ```
>    $problem->setExample6(str_replace(array(',', 'US$', ' '), '', $_POST["example6"]));
>    $_POST["example6"] = $problem->getExample6();
> ```

Comment: You could just remove at PHP level, no? `str_replace(array(',', '$'), '', $string)`.

Comment: I believe `jquery.price_format.2.0.js` is causing issues. Kindly check.

Comment: How to use it based on my post code?

Comment: so, do you know any good java format that I use it instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a javascript approach you could use to strip the `US$`, whitespaces, and commas.

```
var string = 'US$ 625,695,295.00';
alert(string.replace(/(US\$|\s*|,)/g, ''));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8u51grd9/1/

I'd do this in PHP though.

```
$_POST["example6"] = str_replace(array(',', 'US$', ' '), '', $_POST["example6"]);
```

Comment: unfortunately not affected. still its same. it won't save after comma.

Comment: I used your php method str_replace, however it's posting data to table, but not after comma.

Comment: Shouldn't be any commas if that code is being used. https://eval.in/464942 Can you update your question to your current PHP code? Also can you output `$_POST["example6"]` and see if it removed the characters; perhaps there is another character being sent..

Comment: I believe the problem is caused by this line of my post code:    $problem->getExample6();    we need to use something to be matched with this line.

Comment: Output the data along the way and see where it fails and why. I can't guess at what your functions are doing..

Comment: Thank you chris! thums up:)

Comment: @chris85 I hope y'all are doing ok and especially during this time of crisis. Cheers Chris, don't be a stranger *eh!*